# MySQL Dumper creating multiple files - spamming email confirmations

Tags: mysql, backup

It's been a little while since I ran mysql dumper, but have done so successfully in the past many times, however when trying now something weird is happening.

I had not changed the settings (I have now after the problem reset to default to try and fix) but now when I run it I'm getting multiple files generated often 1 second after the other as can be seen in this screenshot of the files on the ftp;

[image]

I had email confirmation turned on too, and I'm pretty much getting an email sent every second as the interface refreshes.

The interface is showing something like this;

[image]

Normally, the last bit *(2 seconds, 0 page refreshes)* might show something like *40 seconds, 25 page refreshes* as it processes bigger databases.

The version of PHP running on the server was updated a little while ago from `5.3` to `5.6.18`. Could that have anything to do with this odd behaviour? As I said, the settings had not been changed - even so the default settings are pretty much what I had used anyway.

**EDIT**

I have also just tried re-downloading mysqldumper from scratch and installing it. Unfortunately, nothing changed. There must be some kind of configuration issue, but I don't know where to find that out...

These are my current settings - they are largely unchanged from the default;
[image]

If i click *auto detect* here I get the value 120795955

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've updated the question with my settings - there are more setting screens, but I've made no changes to them - or everything on them is turned off (FTP for example)

Answer (score 1):

Do not `OPTIMIZE` tables before backups.  That consumes a lot of time, thereby making there by more 1-minute dumps.  And `OPTIMIZE` *rarely* does anything useful.

You have "max file size" = 0 KB -- does that mean unlimited, or small?  I see that the files tend to be a few hundred KB.

Comment: The max file size is disabled unless I check *multipart backup*. I've never used that setting when it worked. However I did test it to see what happened. The same issue occured, only the files had *_part_1* or 2,3 etc.. at the end of them in addition to the duplicate small files seconds apart. Turning off the `OPTIMIZE` option had no effect.